# subquery that contains column name where column value is the lowest

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery

I am trying to create a subquery that only contains the name from an column where another column has the lowest value from 1 table. Can this be done with having, or do I need to use something else?

Example

```
name 1 value 5
name 2 value 7 
name 3 value 2
```

That's in the table I just want name 3 as result in subquery

Comment: Please put more effort in your question. Give table structure, example data and expected output.

Comment: I tryd but it kept saying that i had format errors and i dident now where so i cudent solve them.

Comment: And what happens if there is a name 4 with value 2?, you want 3 and 4 as a result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT NAME
FROM TABLE
WHERE Value in (
   SELECT MIN(VALUE)
   FROM TABLE
   )
```

OR

```
SELECT TOP 1 NAME
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY VALUE
```

Comment: Tanx m8 looks like you better than all the Ponies here they just like to downvote @N1tro

Comment: Anytime.  Glad I could help.

Comment: As mentioned above though, you'll want to make sure your 'value' column has unique values in it or there will be conflicts.